# Backup software for Windows

Tags: windows, backup

Does anybody know of any Windows backup software free / low cost that does direct drive to drive copy and will delete the oldest full back of the drive to prevent it from becoming full? I am thinking along the lines of time machine for Mac but for Windows.

Thanks

Comment: So basically, you're looking for software that will backup 1 drive, and send that backup to the other only keeping as many of the most recent backups that the drive has space for?

Comment: Yes that is write I want multiple full 121 copy's as the back up drive allows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many software: AOMEI Backupper Standard, Comodo BackUp, Todo Backup Free, BackUp Maker. Unfortunately, I tried AOMEI Backupper Standard, but other maybe be too good. There is list of backup software for Windows: http://freeanalogs.com/Windows/Backup

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend the [best backup software for windows](https://yotasoftware.com/software/backup-software-for-windows/) is EaseUS Backup Tool. This software has many advanced features and high performance.

Comment: One of the advanced features is harvesting data for Chinese government I suppose